# Is there a "-=" command for strings in java?

Tags: java, string

I know there is += that adds to the end of a string but is there a -= command? If so, does it subtract from the front or back? What happens if it cannot find what you are trying to -=?

Comment: `The operator -= is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String`

Comment: you should use `substring`

Comment: An operation -= for Strings would be difficult to define: front or back? Or middle? Result when the second string is not a substring of the first? Or only the first few, or last few characters match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `replaceAll`, which i guess is the most accurate for your goal

```
String x = "Strabc"; 
x = x.replaceAll("abc", "");
```

Results in

```
x = "Str";
```

But remember, all the occurrences of `"abc"` will be replaced, so if you have `"abcStrabc"` you will get `"Str"`.

There is the `replace` method that replaces only the first occurrence, so `"abcStrabc"` results in `"Strabc"`

Comment: Actually, `String::replace` also replaces all occurrences. The difference is that `replaceAll` accepts regex while `replace` accepts char sequence, so the latter is more suitable.

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no `-=` operator for strings.

Answer (score 2):

String supports only `+` and `+=`. All other arithmetic  and compound statements are invalid at compile time itself.

From [`String docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings.

That doesn't mean it support all other operations.

To substract or to make parts of string, there are other methods like `substring`, `split` etc.

Here are some examples to substring, from docs

```
 String c = "abc".substring(2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The `x -= y;` operator is short for `x = x - y`. So this should mean there is a *subtraction operator (`-`)*. In this [*Summary of operators*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html), there is no such operator for strings.

Furthermore it is hard to find a *good implementation for `-`*: what is the subtraction supposed to do? Remove the last part of the string? What if the string `x` doesn't end by `y`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want do, `String a = "abc";` 
`a -= 1;` and expect `a = "ab"`?

If yes, use substring,  `a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

NO, I believe there is none. String class does support only `+` operator for concatenation purpose but not `-`; since having `-` operator won't make any sense logically.

Answer (score 0):

```
String chaine = "abcdefgh";
String ch1 = "abc";
chaine = chaine.substring(chaine.indexOf("ch1"),ch1.length()+chaine.indexOf("ch1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not. The compiler returns `bad operand types for binary operator '-'`

Your best bet is to use something like `substring(int beginIndex)` or `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

```
String longString = "I am a string that is too long";
String shortString = longString.substring(0,13); //"I am a string"
```

Here is the Javadoc regarding String objects: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html